# Getting a new first-of-type

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of divs, the first of which is a drag-and-drop target (via ui-droppable). I'm dragging other divs on top of them, like playing cards. I'd like to make both the card and its target disappear when I do that (which I'm currently doing with `.remove()`), then slide the other potential targets upwards and make the top one a valid target.

The first of the target divs (the one that's both "first-of-type" and "ui-droppable") looks different from the others thanks to my css. When I remove the first target, the second one moves up but does not automatically become the new "first" - it doesn't obtain the visual appearance from my css, nor does it now become a valid drag-and-drop target.

Any suggestions on how I can sort of "reset" which element is considered the first after I remove one?

Here's my current code; not very complex.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card').draggable({ revert: true });
    $('.event:first-of-type').droppable({ drop: Drop });
});

function Drop(event, ui) {
    $(this).remove();
    // and then maybe something here to update and get a new "first"?
}
```

Comment: really, adding a class that's named `event:first-of-type` seemed like a good idea ?

Comment: Would be nice with a fiddle... can you post some html?

Comment: `:first-of-type` doesn't do what you think it does. Attaching it to a class selector will often yield unexpected results.

Comment: Your missing the dot on the class selector in the Drop function

Comment: What is the goal of the `addClass` call?

Comment: @adeneo, the drag-and-drop targets are called "events". You're playing action cards in response to a particular event that happens. Am I unintentionally using a keyword there?

Comment: @GruffBunny the "remove" part of the drop function actually works as written. I should have dropped the last line.

Comment: Nope, the selector is quoted, and `event` is not a reserved keyword, so that shouldn't be an issue, but you're literally adding a class called `event:first-of-type`

Comment: @adeneo ah, ok. Got it. That part's gone from my example code now; thanks - it was a failed attempt to reset a "first" and apparently failed for multiple reasons.

Comment: @BoltClock that's nice to know but unfortunately not helpful. Can you perhaps point me towards something more informative?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/

Comment: @Sergio here you go. The HTML, code, and css are all here in a big paste; you can probably tell which is which. http://pastebin.com/d3C0Lx03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dragged, first;
    $('.card').draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            dragged = this;
            first = $('div.card:first');
            Drop();
        },
        revert: true
    });

    // When we drop a card on the "today" event, call the Drop function.
    function Drop() {
        first.droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(this);
                $(this).remove();
                $(dragged).remove();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gYFE5/)

Comment: Not bad. Except for the target needing to be an event rather than a card, that's essentially the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: @ColinFredericks, what is missing? both cards are removed and you get a new first card active to be dropped

Comment: Had to change `div.card:first` to `div.event:first`. Other than that it works great. I may also need to implement McPhelpsius' approach below, but this gets me the UI that I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should just store them in an array.

`.push()` them into the array as they "disappear", which should probably just be assigning a `display:none` css class to them.  Then, as you turn the card over, take the last item in the array (the most recently pushed item) and remove the class.

This is all just guessing from you limited description, but something along those lines should work.